# Python: Accessing indices of iterable passed into `Pool.map(function(), iterable)`

Tags: indexing, multiprocessing, pool, iterable

I have code that looks something like this:

```
    def downloadImages(self, path):
        for link in self.images: #self.images=list of links opened via requests & written to file
           if stuff in link:
                #parse link a certain way to get `name`
           else:
                #parse link a different way to get `name`
           r = requests.get(link)
           with open(path+name,'wb') as f:
               f.write(r.content)

pool = Pool(2)
scraper.prepPage(url)
scraper.downloadImages('path/to/directory')
```

I want to change `downloadImages` to parallelize the function. Here's my attempt:

```
    def downloadImage(self, path, index of self.images currently being processed):
       if stuff in link: #because of multiprocessing, there's no longer a loop providing a reference to each index...the index is necessary to parse and complete the function.
            #parse link a certain way to get `name`
       else:
           #parse link a different way to get `name`
       r = requests.get(link)
       with open(path+name,'wb') as f:
           f.write(r.content)

pool = Pool(2)
scraper.prepPage(url)
pool.map(scraper.downloadImages('path/to/directory', ***some way to grab index of self.images****), self.images)
```

How can I refer to the index currently being worked on of the iterable passed into `pool.map()`?

I'm completely new to multiprocessing & couldn't find what I was looking for in the documentation...I also couldn't find a similar question via google or stackoverflow.